# I can't solve a task on LeetCode, repeats me that i have a wrong answer and I tried to run it on my pc, the answer is right

Tags: java

I am trying to send a sollution, but i have the same problem every time: The code on my computer works good, but it doesnt work properly on LeetCode.
The task: https://leetcode.com/problems/jump-game-ii/description/

My code:

```
class Solution {
    public static ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    
    public int jump(int[] nums) {
        dfs(nums, 0, 0);
        int minStepsToFinish = list.stream().min(Integer::compare).get();
        return minStepsToFinish;
    }

    public static void dfs(int[] nums, int current, int step) {
        if(current == nums.length-1) {
            list.add(step);
            return;
        }
        step++;
        for (int j = 1; j <= nums[current]; j++) {
            dfs(nums, current + j, step);
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to check if my program returns incorrect answers, but it works good. For example: when input is [1,2] it returns 1, however LeetCode says that my return is 0.

Comment: Don't use static list, make it a local variable instead (put initialization and assignment into the jump method; then pass it into the dfs), otherwise, it is re-used between the test runs on leetcode, which messes up its contents.

Comment: Poor title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.